# Como resolver bug do Ubuntu 16.04 com a placa de rede Qualcomm Atheros

Tags: ubuntu, driver

Artigo:
Alguns passos para serem realizados:

Realize a configuração:

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
```

Baixe o repositório e copie os drivers

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/WLAN.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não pertence ao escopo deste site. Leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tente a sequencia de comandos para ver se lhe ajuda:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp *  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1  firmware-5.bin
```

Reinicie e sua wifi deveria funcionar.

Comment: Algum motivo aparente para o downvote ?

Comment: O downvote não é meu, mas suspeito que o seu motivo esteja relacionado com ter sido considerada off topic.

Comment: @Isac mesmo sendo off não custa tentar ajudar

Comment: Respondendo você incentiva o usuario a fazerem esse tipo de pergunta aqui e da brecha a outros fazerem o mesmo. Você pode ajudar nos comentários se quiser, respondendo, geralmente o resultado é sempre esse.